# Does Avro schema updating work with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am doing an eval of BigQuery, and trying to update an Avro table with a new column in that table, but it does not seem to be working.  Here is what I am doing:

1) upload data to GCS

```
$ gsutil cp book.avro gs://analytics-145623.appspot.com/bob/v1/book.avro

$ gsutil cp book2.avro gs://analytics-145623.appspot.com/bob/v2/book2.avro
```

book.avro has 3 records, each with 3 fields

book2.avro has 3 records, each with 4 fields

2) create the table

```
$ bq mk analytics.bob_test01
```

3) create the first version of the table, which works fine

```
$ bq load --source_format=AVRO analytics.bob_test01 \ 
  gs://analytics-145623.appspot.com/bob/v1/book.avro
```

4) create the second version of the table

```
$ bq load --source_format=AVRO --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION analytics.bob_test01 gs://analytics-145623.appspot.com/bob/v2/book2.avro
```

The new data gets appended to the table, but the new column is not in the table.  If go back to the UI and manually add the column and rerun the load, then the data appears as expected, but that is not exactly what I want.  I want the usual schema evolution.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. 
We identified this as a bug and will fix it soon.

Comment: @xuejian Thanks for getting back, since we are still evaluating and considering moving from Redshift to BQ, any idea of a timeline, it would really help in our decision-making?

Comment: @xuejian a better question to answer would be does this work correctly via the API?  We are planning on kicking jobs off from an action node in Oozie, so if it works in the API then that would be fine.  If the bug is in the CLI, we can certainly live with that.  Ideas?

Comment: The bug is in the back-end, so you'll run into the same problem using the API. We should be able to get this fixed and released by end of next week.

Comment: Sorry, spoken too fast. Apparently Christmas is coming and we will freeze our weekly releases. This should go out in the first week of Jan. 2017 when the freeze ends.

Comment: Awesome, that will work!

Comment: @HuaZhang how has this patch progressed? any news?

Comment: The fix is done and should be deployed to production next week.